# Laravel view can not show the data

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel, in the demo below,there is something wrong,the data can not be shown in view:

**demo:**

article.blade.php

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
  {{$article}}
@endforeach
```

result in browser：

```
{"id":1,"title":"hello world","content":"demo","created_at":"2017-07-23 15:34:52","updated_at":"2017-07-23 15:34:55"}
```

But it has error below:

article.blade.php

```
@foreach ($articles as $article)
  {{$article->title}}
@endforeach
```

error：

```
Property [title] does not exist on this collection instance.
```

why is it？

**update:**

result of `dd($articles)`:
And I need this data structure,dont modify it, the outer array can be mofidied to a collection.

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => Collection {#485 ▼
    #items: array:6 [▼
      "id" => 1
      "title" => "hello"
      "content" => "hello world"
      "user_id" => 2
      "tags" => Collection {#505 ▼
        #items: array:2 [▼
          0 => Tag {#506 ▶}
          1 => Tag {#508 ▶}
        ]
      }
      "created_at" => "2017-07-23 15:34:52"
      "updated_at" => "2017-07-23 15:34:55"
    ]
  }
  1 => Collection {#500 ▼
    #items: array:6 [▼
      "id" => 2
      "title" => "foo"
      "content" => "foo bar"
      "user_id" => 2
      "tags" => Collection {#505 ▼
        #items: array:2 [▼
          0 => Tag {#506 ▶}
          1 => Tag {#508 ▶}
        ]
      }
      "created_at" => "2017-07-23 16:27:43"
      "updated_at" => "2017-07-23 16:27:46"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: How do you get `$articles`? Please show result of `{{ dd($articles) }}`

Comment: If `$article` is a collection, you need to do e.g. `$article->get('title')` or `$article['title']`.

Comment: Actually, if `$articles` is a collection, your foreach should look like this one `@foreach ($articles->get() as $article)`. This converts the collection (non-iterable) into an array of objects (iterable).

Comment: @zwl1619 Could you share your method code ?

Comment: @Nour it'ok. Another question, `{{$article->updated_at->format('Y-m-d')}}` becomes `{{$article['updated_at']}}`,how to show the `format('Y-m-d')`?

Comment: @zwl1619 `date('Y-m-d', strtotime($article->updated_at));` or you can use `Carbon` https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Answer (score 0):

You can try with

```
@foreach ($articles as $a)
  {{$a->title}}
@endforeach
```

I know it's like a miracle but sometime, it work like a charm.